# How to assure that JUnit @Before has an accompanying @After

Tags: java, junit

Today I bumped into my own mess: some gigabytes of temporary test data in temp folders created by JUnit's `TemporaryFolder`s that weren't cleaned up.

It appears to be that if your test does not have a `@After` method, the `@Rule`s are not `after()`ed, either.

Is there a way to assure (programmatorically) that a test with a `@Before` method also has *at least* one `@After` method, too?

Answer (score 4):

Presence of absence of an `@After` method has no effect on JUnit rules. In general, `@After` is used much less often than `@Before` in JUnit tests. If the `TemporaryFolder` rule didn't clean up, then it probably wasn't successful deleting the files, for example due to a file permission problem. As you can tell from `TemporaryFolder`'s source code, you won't get an error or warning in such a case (the return value of `File.delete` isn't used). Another possibility is that the JVM crashed or was terminated by the party controlling test execution (IDE, build tool, CI server).

Answer (score 0):

You could run through all your test files and examine the contents to make sure that is @Before is present then @After is as well. I do this kind of thing quite a bit, and I find it runs sufficiently swiftly to include in a unit test suite.

Of course this won't prove that you are doing the right thing in your @After method.

Something like this should get you started

```
for (File file : new File(yourTestDirectory).listFiles()) {
   for (String contents : Files.toString(file, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    if(contents.contains("@Before")){
      if(!contents.contains("@After"){
        fail("must have @Before and @After");
      }
    }
  }
}
```